# Extra line below aligned(at)

Tags: align, alignment

This issue has arised in my work numerous times. Consider the following equation:
[image]
(I moved the bottom line using the image editor and do not have a decent code producing the desired output. Originally, I had a superlong fourth line in the system.)

Imagine for a second there's no bottom line beginning with 'and'. Then, the 'cases' can be trivially produced with the aid of

```
\left\{\begin{aligned}
...
\end{aligned}\right.
```

Is there a simple way to modify such a code to produce the bottom line **which would be aligned in a desired way with the line above**?

A brute-force yet quite universal solution which I sometimes employed was to create an invisible table. In the present case, smth like 5x4...

A rather trivial option would be to use another `alignedat` for the two lines in the bottom right. An obvious problem is that they will be vertically centered relative to the line to the left. But probably there's a way to overcome it?.. It would be really nice, since such `aligned` would naturally permit for the desired alignment.

Yet another good solution would be to make the original `aligned` span all the five lines and then somehow produce the bracket on the left covering just the first four lines, together with the equal sign. What's the best way to do so? The only thing coming to my mind is to create a 2x2 invisible table...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would have been much easier to experiment with if there had been a compilable example.  I haven't tried to replicate it exactly, just to produce the desired structure.

Here's the approximation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{align*}
& \{(\tilde{n}_1, \tilde{m}_1), (\tilde{n}_2, \tilde{m}_2), \dots,
   (\tilde{n}_I, \tilde{m}_I)\} \ominus
  \{(\tilde{n}'_1, \tilde{m}'_1), (\tilde{n}'_2, \tilde{m}'_2), \dots,
   (\tilde{n}'_I, \tilde{m}'_I)\} \\
& \begin{cases}
   \{(\tilde{n}_i, 1), (\tilde{n}'_j, 1)\} &
     \text{s.t. } \tilde{n}_i \ne \tilde{n}'_j. \text{ or} \\
   \{(\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}'_j, 1)\} &
     \text{s.t. } (\tilde{n}_j, m_j) = (\tilde{n}'_j. m_j) \\
   \{(\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}'_j, 1)\} &
     \text{s.t. } (\tilde{n}_j, m_j) = (\tilde{n}'_j. m_j) \\
   \{(\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}_i, m_i), (\tilde{n}'_j, 1)\} &
     \text{s.t. }
       \smash[b]
        {\begin{aligned}[t]
           (\tilde{n}_j, m_j) = (\tilde{n}'_j. m_j) \\
           (\tilde{n}_j, m_j) = (\tilde{n}'_j. m_j)
        \end{aligned}}
  \end{cases}\\[-6pt]
\end{align*}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

In answer to a comment "How does it work?", here are the important components.  (All are provided by `amsmath`.)

(a) `cases` groups multiple lines with a brace on the left.

(b) `aligned` is used to split the final line of the cases group into two lines.  The `[t]` option continues the first line of the `aligned` subgroup at the same level as what precedes it.  (Other questions on this site also deal with this operation.)

(c) In order to keep the brace from extending down to include the final line, `\smash[b]` is applied to the two-line (`aligned`) element on the last line.  (`[b]` stands for "bottom".)  This makes (La)TeX think that nothing extends below the first line of the `aligned` element, effectively reducing the depth of the cases alignment to four lines.

(d) This also affects the spacing between the display and the text that follows, so that needs to be adjusted.  I chose to add an extra line with `\\` just before the end of the outer `align*`, and adjust the spacing by decreasing the skip after the display.

Comment: 1. Amazing, thanks! 2. How does it work???.. o_O